# On my MacBook Pro, “open with” and selecting “change all” does not seem to work for PSD files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, psd

I have both Photoshop CC 2018 and Adobe Photoshop CS6 installed on my MacBook Pro (OS 10.13.2). The association for some PSD files remains set to Adobe Photoshop CS6.

While I can change the association for individual PSD files to Photoshop CC 2018, but if select “change all” it doesn’t take and it automatically reverts back to Adobe Photoshop CS6.

I have run “repair disk” from Disk Utility, but it found no problems, and hasn’t changed the behavior.

Comment: There have been a few complaints about Change All behaviour recently - maybe see if [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) can still do it. [It's old but has worked for many many years] I'm not on HS so can't test.